# Insert into mysql using div codes and php

Tags: php, html, sql

the below to functions contain the code to insert into the sql database but sadly the db is still unable to load it to the database.

```
if (isset($_POST['register'])){

    if(registerNewUser($_POST['inv_amount_expected'],$_POST['uname'],$_POST['passwo    rd'],$_POST['email'])){

        echo "You can now log-in to your account.
            <a href='./index.php'>Click here to login.</a>
        ";

    }else {

        echo "Registration failed! Please try again.";
        show_registration_form();

    }

} else {
    // has not pressed the register button
    show_registration_form();   
}

function registerNewUser($inv_amount_expected,$uname,$password,$email)
{
    $sql = sprintf("insert into borrow (inv_amount_expected,uname,password,email) value ('&inv_amount_expected','&uname','&password','&email')",
        mysql_real_escape_string($username), mysql_real_escape_string(sha1($password . $seed))
        , mysql_real_escape_string($email), mysql_real_escape_string($code));


    if (mysql_query($sql))
    {
        $id = mysql_insert_id();
        return true;
    } 

    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    return false;

}
```

could you help me out in where i am going wrong since im unable to understand.
i'm still an amature in php so please help me out.

Comment: **Stop**  using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` Learn about prepared statements

Comment: Your [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) looks wrongly used.

Comment: You should switch from `mysql_*` as it has been [officially](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) deprecated. Use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) **with** [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: `$_POST['passwo    rd']` nice spacing too.

Answer (score 0):

I am putting my ideas together and at the moment i have the following:

-a mysql database with 2 tables.
-the first table "downloads" contains 3 rows, each with a unique id that and each represent the type of file being downloaded. e.g. application or theme.
-the second table contains the information about each download, these fields are the models supported by the download, the title, a picture, a brief description and a download link. each download has a unique id.

Now what i am trying to do is insert the data into a set of divs, these divs are as follows:

```
<div class="dlcontainer">
 <div class="dlitem">
  <div class="dltitle"><php $row['title'] ?></div>";
  <div class="dlimage"><php $row['image'] ?></div>";
  <div class="dldescription"><php $row['description'] ?></div>";
  <div class="dllink"><php $row['downlink'] ?></div>";
 </div>
</div>
```

As you can see i have been trying to populate the divs with information called from the database and that was my first attempt.

I didn't feel like i was going about this with the right approach, so i ended up with this, which also does not seem to work:

```
&lt;?php
$con = mysql_connect("test","test","test");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("test", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `content` WHERE pid = '2' AND models = 'all' OR models = $chosen");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

  {
    echo "&lt;div class=\\"dlcontainer\\"&gt;";
     echo "&lt;div class=\\"dlitem\\"&gt;";
      echo "&lt;div class=\\"dltitle\\"&gt;$row['title']&lt;/div&gt;";
      echo "&lt;div class=\\"dlimage\\"&gt;$row['image']&lt;/div&gt;";
      echo "&lt;div class=\\"dldescription\\"&gt;$row['description']&lt;/div&gt;";
      echo "&lt;div class=\\"dllink\\"&gt;$row['downlink']&lt;/div&gt;";
     echo "&lt;/div&gt;";
    echo "&lt;/div&gt;";
  }
     mysql_close($con);
?&gt;
```

Once i get this initial download working, i can then set up a loop that will display all the contents that match belong to a specific "pid" and either match a "models" value of "all" or one that has been selected by the user.